# Is experience with foreign clients valuable for resume?

Tags: resume

I am working in an industry that communicate regularly with foreign clients.
Do you think it's worthy to be mentioned in my resume?

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question? What kind of client are they? How are you communicating with them? Is there a reason you might be hesitant to list this experience on your resume?

Answer (score 8):

Anything you believe is relevant to the job you're applying for should be in your resume. If you think you'll be dealing with foreign clients in your new job, then you should state it. If it's a job where you won't be dealing with foreign clients just briefly mention it and leave it at a mention.

Your resume should show everything you can do whilst showing how what you can do is relevant to what you **will be** doing.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this depends how important it is to your job, but it's also important to notice which culture you're used to dealing with. If you have a lot experience in dealing with Asian clients that would be a huge plus in any job it is relevant to.

This is because Asian cultures are particularly strong and as such having experience in navigating them can be quite valuable.

So think about two things:

- Is it important for the job.
- Is it a culture that is hard to navigate.

If you can answer yes to one of the questions I'd mention it. If you can answer yes to both I'd make it a bigger point.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, list the experience on your resume if you are excited to share it and believe it represents your capabilities well.**

Experience with foreign clients, even if you didn't work abroad, is great. **It demonstrates a number of capabilities that a domestic experience does not:**

**1. You're capable of managing remote work.** Either you managed a project remotely or the implementation was remote - in both cases, managing work over a long distance is a great skill.

**2. You're able to make use of electronic communication effectively.** Whether it was over the phone or over email, your long-distance contacts were not in person. Being able to effectively make use of these more challenging ways of communicating is another great skill.

**3. You can adapt to the norms of another culture.** Working with individuals from another culture according to that culture's norms is a great experience. It means you possess both empathy and great observation skills to be able to modulate your behavior in the presence of people unlike you.

**4. You're willing to work outside of your comfort zone.** Foreign assignments are tough because they force us to work according to new routines, norms and communication methods. Having completed these assignments is a great demonstration of your willingness to take on more challenging work.

---

I'm sure a recruiter will be delighted by this experience on your resume! Best of luck in your job hunt.